# "VS Code closed unexpectedly" error message pops up but it still runs

Tags: error-handling, visual-studio-code

I had a VS Code window opened with an .ipynb file inside and suddenly i got two error messages in a row with difference of about 20 secs which said something like "vs code unexpectedly closed" but actually my VS Code didn't close (forgot to take a screenshot of this message)
Why could this happen? It looked kinda suspicious.

p.s. im a newcomer in ubuntu so i decided to ask this maybe kinda stupid question

Comment: ubuntu 22.04.1 lts btw

Comment: Without knowing the exact message, it will be difficult to answer this accurately. Applications can unexpectedly close if they run into a coding fault or a memory issue, though. It's also important to remember that many applications run several threads, so it may not be the entire program that failed, but one or more threads that have terminated without a proper exit code.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i cant provide the exact message. So probably there can't be any more accurate answer.
Thanks!